# How to display greater data linked list

Tags: c++, linked-list

I just learn to display data using linked list and I want to add function to display data greater than 10 but It's getting error ISO C++ Forbids Comparison Between Pointer and Integer [-fpermissive]. I don't know how to fix my code

```
void DisplayList(void){
            Node* temp = new Node;
            temp = head;
            while(temp != NULL){
                cout<<temp -> data<<" ";
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            cout<<endl;
        }

void GreaterList(void){
            Node* temp = new Node;
            temp =head;
            while(temp != NULL){
                if(temp >= 10){
                cout<<temp->data<<" ";
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to get the data from the node to do the comparison :

```
void GreaterList(void){
            Node* temp = new Node;
            temp = head;
            while(temp != NULL){
                if(temp->data >= 10){ // <== Here
                cout<<temp->data << " ";
                temp = temp->next;
            }
        }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to Stackoverflow.

Your problem is quite simply a type problem.
You need to dereference your temp pointer to get the actual value and compare it with an integer.

```
while(*temp >= 10){
   ...
}
´´´
```